# BlockingOperationError when using multipart data through webclient

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, spring-webclient, blockhound

I'm trying to upload/stream multipart data to another backend service API, which received through `ServerRequest` in webflux. It's working fine except I'm getting following exception when enabling `Blockhound` to verify any non-blocking call

```
reactor.blockhound.BlockingOperationError: Blocking call! java.io.FileInputStream#readBytes
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(FileInputStream.java)
    at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:271)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:132)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.readFully(NativePRNG.java:424)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.ensureBufferValid(NativePRNG.java:526)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG$RandomIO.implNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:545)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.NativePRNG.engineNextBytes(NativePRNG.java:220)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:751)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:808)
    at java.base/java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:390)
    at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.generateMultipartBoundary(MimeTypeUtils.java:390)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartWriterSupport.generateMultipartBoundary(MultipartWriterSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageWriter.writeMultipart(MultipartHttpMessageWriter.java:185)
    at org.springframework.http.codec.multipart.MultipartHttpMessageWriter.lambda$write$0(MultipartHttpMessageWriter.java:158)
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.trySubscribeScalarMap(FluxFlatMap.java:152)
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribeOrReturn(MonoFlatMap.java:53)
```

Code :

```
    MultipartBodyBuilder builder = new MultipartBodyBuilder();
    builder.part("document", filepart).filename(filepart.filename());
    builder.part("stringParam", stringParam);

    WebClient webClient = webClientBuilder.build();
    return webClient.post()
            .uri("/service/backend")
            .contentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromMultipartData(builder.build()))
            .retrieve();
```

Could anyone share input to resolve this issue ?

System info :

```
OS     : Mac OS
Spring : 5.3.12
Java   : 1.8
```

Comment: `WebClient` uses `SecureRandom.next` to generate unique identifiers for `MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` that is blocking. You could allow it or switch execution to `boundedElastic` scheduler. It's really depends on your use case bit in many scenarios it's ok to allow this call.
There are [some issues on GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/search?q=%22SecureRandom%22&type=issues) where you could get more info .

Comment: @Alex where do I mention `boundedElastic` ? since, it was occurring while constructing final request before sending to backend API. Is it on the webclient call ?

Comment: you could use it directly on Webclient `.retrieve().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())` or on the method level `uploadFile().subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())`
At the same time, looking at this blocking call, you could possibly ignore it and run some load tests to validate.

Comment: does not seems to work @Alex